# How can I convert xfunction Pointer to Java array?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, jna

I have Java application which sends pointer to function (callback) to some native dll kernel.
I use xfunction library for manipulations with the native code. I have to handle int* pointer as an array of integers within callback body. In fact, I have com.excelsior.xFunction.Pointer object. I need to make some tricks for transforming com.excelsior.xFunction.Pointer => int [] array.
Can JNA library help (using com.sun.jna.Pointer, IntByReference)?

For example,  com.excelsior.xFunction.Pointer => com.sun.jna.Pointer => int [] array.
I don't want to rewrite code in order to eliminate calls to xfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XFunction does not seem to give the ability to fetch back the native pointer. Since it's not opensourced and their falgship product is a Java obfuscator I think you're stuck and won't be able to do com.excelsior.xFunction.Pointer => com.sun.jna.Pointer.

So, as they say ( http://www.excelsior-usa.com/xfunction.html ) :

> We [...] encourage you to look first at JNA

I think you'd better to recode this part of your app in full JNA to do what you want ... or stick with XFunction

Anyway, if you manage to find a way to fetch back XFunction's native pointer just cast it to a Java `long` and pass it to JNA's [`new com.sun.jna.Pointer(long)`](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#Pointer%28long%29) and then just do
 a [`com.sun.jna.Pointer.getIntArr(offset,arrayLength)`](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getIntArray%28long,%20int%29) to fetch back the array in pure Java